# socket id of the wrong client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io.

I export the socket, in order to use it in different modules:

```
   io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        //export socket to be used throughout the application
        exports.socket = socket;

//more code...

 });
```

I send messages from other modules using this function:

```
var sendJSONReport = function (report) {
    report.client_id = require("./socketMngr").socket.id;
    var msg = JSON.stringify(report);
    require("./socketMngr").socket.emit('sent JSON Report', msg);
};
```

in my client side js, I console.log the sent messages.

I open two chrome tabs and run the application on both with different data. 
I see that one of the tabs gets messages that are supposed to reach the other. The client_id is the same as messages that are supposed to reach that tab, meaning the server sends to the wrong client id.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each new connection will trigger the `connection` event, with a different `socket` for each client connection. On your handler in the first code snippet, you are clobbering the `exports.socket` value, each time a new connection is made. This means that the latest client will receive any new messages meant for any previous clients.

You need to re-organize your code, and store the socket in the module that has the `sendJSONReport` function by creating a new instance and passing it the socket id on each `connection` event.

Comment: Thanks... I tried to follow your advice: I pass socket.id as a parameter, I export io, and i emit like this: require("./socketMngr").io.sockets.socket(socket_id).emit('sent JSON Report', msg); The problem persists. Can you tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow... Can you edit your question and add the file names for each of the snippets of code? Also add at least code from one of the modules that uses this `sendJSONReport` function.

Comment: I found my bug... Thnx alot :)

Comment: glad to hear you were able to fix it